Existence of infinite rank compact operator
Given any separable Banach space $X$, we know that always there exists a Banach space $Y$ such that there is an injective compact operator from $X$ to $Y$. Can we show that given any infinite dimensional Banach space $X$, there exists an infinite dimensional Banach space $Y$ and a compact operator $T:X\to Y$ such that $T$ is not of finite rank. My guess is "YES"! but I am unable to find any reference in my support. Any help is appreciated.

So the question is you want to remove the separability assumption on $X$? The usual proof of the statement in your first sentence should be easily adaptable to prove the result you want.

In $X^*$, choose a sequence of linearly independent (in algebraic sense: no non-trivial finite linear combination is 0) unit norm functionals $f_1,f_2,\ldots$ Define $T$ from $X$ to $c_0$ by $T(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x)/2,f_3(x)/3,\ldots)$. This operator is compact (because the image of the unit ball has a finite-dimensional $\varepsilon$-net for every $\varepsilon>0$), and its image has infinite dimension, otherwise, if dimension was $d$, the first $d+1$ functionals $f_i$would be linearly dependent.
